# What type of topology is used to form a MAN or WAN?

Tags: networking, lan, wan

I'm reading about different types of network topologies used to form a LAN:

- Bus
- Ring
- Star
- Tree
- Line
- Mesh

Do they participate in MAN or WAN? Are there different methods to form a MAN or WAN?

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why a MAN or a WAN couldn't use any of those topologies or a mix of them.

These categories are not always distinct. This reminds me of token-ring networks, logically a ring, physically a star or tree.